# Executing control statements in zsh?

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2

This feels like a dumb question but I'm on a mac using iterm with zsh and I've been reading the zsh manual and am trying to execute `^Xh` to query the completion parameters, but whenever I do

```
ls ^Xh
```

And either hit enter or tab, I just get an error.  I'm hitting the control key with x then hitting h. Am I missing something totally obvious here?

Comment: I don't know iterm2, but perhaps it is catching ^x. You could try if `bindkey '^w' _complete_help` works, which binds the display of the completion parameters to `CTRL+W`.

Comment: This worked great. I tried in a regular terminal and cntrl+Xh didn't do anything but the bind key did. THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long long after I realized that the zsh control statements are only for emacs mode, and I was in vi mode.  To do the control statements I need to switch back to emacs mode

```
set -o emacs
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm hitting the control key then hitting h. Am I missing something totally obvious here?

Yes.

`^Xh` → <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that's what I was doing in my question and yet I don't get the zsh completion help